# Solve implicit system of equations

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

Hello everybody I try to solve this system of functions and try to plot it:

```
x == 0.5(1.+Tanh[0.5*(x*y^2-eps1)/t]
y == Tanh[(x^2*y+eps2)/t]
```

with eps1 = 0. and eps2 = 1, for instance. The problem is how I can not only solve it but plot for instance x vs. t and y vs. t . Is it possible to do it in Mathematica?

Can I use first Solve[...,....,{x,y}] and explicit, for example, x as functions of t and y and then plot it?

I have the plot of the sol_x vs. t attached [image: here]

The numbers correspond to different values of eps2 that, in my example is equal to 1.

**Discontinuities for particular parameters**

As mention by `MarcoB` the code to solve this algebraic system of equation can be written as follow:

```
s1 = Table[{t, x} /. 
    FindRoot[{x == 1/2 (1 + Tanh[1/2 (x y^2 - eps)/t]), 
      y == Tanh[(x^2 y + h)/t]}, {x, 1.}, {y, 1.}], {t, .001, 1.5, 
    1/100}];

ListLinePlot[s1, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0., 1.}}, 
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05], Frame -> True]
```

Where h, eps are two constant parameters. Now when I take **particular** parameters for h, eps (for instance: h = 0. and eps = 0. ) I have discontinuity while for other parameters I obtain smooth function. 
So this [image: strange behaviour] near the discontinuity is because `FindRoot` can't be able to converge? Or because there is some problem in accuracy? I try with `AccuracyGoal` and number of iterations but nothing change. Is it possible, somehow to fix this problem ?

Many thanks

Comment: It is about what language? What is `**`?

Comment: Start by expressing your equations in proper *Mathematica* syntax (e.g. tanh() is really `TanH[]`, `**` is probably `^` ), then look into `ParametricPlot`.

Comment: Also note that equations use `==`, not `=`. Finally, how is `C` in your plot above calculated from the equations you show?

Answer (score 3):

`Solve` seems unable to solve your system symbolically. One can solve it numerically for various values of $t$, $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$.

Setting `eps1 = 0` as you indicated, we can use the following:

```
eps1 = 0;

Table[
  {t, x} /. FindRoot[
    {
     x == 1/2 (1 + Tanh[1/2 (x y^2 - eps1)/t]),
     y == Tanh[(x^2 y + eps2)/t]
    },
    {x, 1},
    {y, 1}
  ],
  {eps2, 1, 6, 1},
  {t, 1*^-9, 15/10, 1/100}
];

ListLinePlot[%,
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0.5, 1}},
 PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05], Frame -> True,
 Epilog -> Text[Style["eps1 = " <> ToString[N@eps1], 18], Scaled[{0.8, 0.8}]],
 PlotLegends -> (("eps2 = " <> ToString[#]) & /@ Range[6])
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, this does not reproduce your graph very well, even for different values of `eps1`. You should provide a link to the source of the plot you showed and some context for your system of equations.

Answer (score 1):

This may help, your problematic jump occurs because you have multiple solutions:

```
With[{t = 1/2, h = 0, eps = 0},
 ContourPlot[{
   x == 1/2 (1 + Tanh[(x y^2 + eps)/t]),
   y == Tanh[(x^2 y + h)/t]}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, -1, 1}]]
```

[image]