# Equation Solving, intersection of graphs

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

How can I find the points where these two graphs intersect:

```
ContourPlot[{x == 1/2 (1 + Tanh[(x y^2)/0.5]),y == Tanh[(x^2 y)/0.5]}, 
{x, 0, 2}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: this is a dup, here is one : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/124239/2079.  (I'm pretty sure that exact contour plot is in a question someplace)

Comment: Also this one: [Updating Wagon's FindAllCrossings2D function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/275/17)

Comment: In adoption of the manual page for `MeshFunctions` one can directly plot the solution with a "one-liner" `ContourPlot[{f[x, y], g[x, y]}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 MeshFunctions -> {f[#1, #2] - g[#1, #2] &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
 MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]]`

Comment: here you go, that exact function.. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/112909/2079

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FindRoot` is the first thing that comes to mind with this type of problems. First, create a list of initial conditions for the root search, based on the plot (rough estimates are sufficient):

```
init = {{0.5, 0}, {0.75, 0.75}, {0.75, -0.75}, {1, 1}, {1, -1}};
```

Make a pure function that will find the roots:

```
f = FindRoot[{x == 1/2 (1 + Tanh[(x y^2)/0.5]), y == Tanh[(x^2 y)/0.5]}, {{x, #1}, {y, #2}}] &
```

and apply it to the initial conditions:

```
roots = f @@@ init
```

> {{x -> 0.5, y -> 0.}, {x -> 0.764865, y -> 0.620918}, {x -> 0.764865, 
>     y -> -0.620918}, {x -> 0.969417, y -> 0.944097}, {x -> 0.969417, 
>     y -> -0.944097}}

or just

```
{x, y} /. roots
```

> {{0.5, 0.}, {0.764865, 0.620918}, {0.764865, -0.620918}, {0.969417, 
>     0.944097}, {0.969417, -0.944097}}

---

**EDIT:** I developed a different method, suitable for this problem also, while answering [another question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127163/22013).

Let's take the plot in the form

```
curve = ContourPlot[{x == 1/2 (1 + Tanh[(x y^2)/0.5]), 
   y == Tanh[(x^2 y)/0.5]}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, -1, 1}, Frame -> None, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

and extract the pixel positions of intersection with

```
px = PixelValuePositions[#, White] & @
  MorphologicalBranchPoints @ Thinning @ Binarize @ ColorNegate @ curve
```

We need to connect them to the actual coordinates on the plot:

```
pl = PlotRange@curve
```

> {{0., 2.}, {-1., 1.}}

```
id = ImageDimensions@curve
```

> {360, 360}

The relation between `pl` and `id` is linear, $y=ax+b$ and $y=cx+d$ in the horizontal and vertical directions, respecively:

```
{a, b} = {a, b} /. 
  First@Solve[{pl[[1, 1]] == b, pl[[1, 2]] == a id[[1]] + b}, {a, b}]
{c, d} = {c, d} /. 
  First@Solve[{pl[[2, 1]] == d, pl[[2, 2]] == c id[[2]] + d}, {c, d}]
```

> {0.00555556, 0.}
>
> {0.00555556, -1.}

The pixel positions transformed to plot coordinates:

```
ic = {a #1 + b, c #2 + d} & @@@ px
```

> {{0.983333, 0.961111}, {0.988889, 0.955556}, {0.977778, 
>     0.95}, {0.961111, 0.933333}, {0.783333, 0.638889}, {0.761111, 
>     0.605556}, {0.755556, 0.6}, {0.761111, 0.594444}, {0.505556, 
>     0.}, {0.711111, 0.}, {0.716667, 
>     0.}, {0.761111, -0.594444}, {0.755556, -0.6}, {0.761111, \
>   -0.605556}, {0.777778, -0.638889}, {0.961111, -0.933333}, {0.977778, \
>   -0.95}}

look like this:

[image]

Not exactly at the intersections, but this is good enough. We can get rid of the ambiguity with clustering:

```
clu = ClusterClassify[ic, Method -> "DBSCAN"]
```

> Number of clusters: 6

```
g = GatherBy[ic, clu]
icmean = Reverse[Mean /@ g]
```

> {{0.969444, -0.941667}, {0.763889, -0.609722}, {0.713889, 
>     0.}, {0.505556, 0.}, {0.765278, 0.609722}, {0.977778, 0.95}}

```
Show[curve, Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Point[#]}] &@icmean]
```

[image]

which looks very good. The additional intersection of the orange curve with itself was found additinally.

Comment: how do I make sure only to find intersection between yellow and blue line, but not intersection between the line of the same colour?