# obtain a list of values

Tags: plotting

I used the method to find solutions on the graph t1 and t2

```
Clear[q, r]
q[t1_, t2_] := 
 0.25*(2*(Cos[t1] - Cos[t2])/(t2 - t1) - 2*Sin[t1])^4 + 
  0.25 (-Cos[t1] + (Sin[t2] - Sin[t1])/(t2 - t1))^4
r[t1_, t2_, En_] := 
 0.25` ((2 (Cos[t1] - Cos[t2]))/(-t1 + t2) - 2 Sin[t2])^4 + 
  0.25` (-Cos[t2] + (-Sin[t1] + Sin[t2])/(-t1 + t2))^4 - En
Show[{ContourPlot[{q[t1, t2] == 1, r[t1, t2, 0.4] == 0}, {t1, -\[Pi], 
    2*\[Pi]}, {t2, 0, 10 \[Pi]}, 
   ContourStyle -> {Lighter[Brown, .7], GrayLevel[.7]}], 
  ContourPlot[
   q[t1, t2] == 1, {t1, -\[Pi], 2*\[Pi]}, {t2, 0, 10 \[Pi]}, 
   ContourStyle -> None, 
   MeshFunctions -> Function[{t1, t2}, r[t1, t2, 0.4]], Mesh -> {{0}},
    MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[4.5]]]}]
```

Please, Could you tell me, Can I get the node values (red dots) in the form of values of t1 and t2 or how I can make a plot E(t2)?

```
Ee[t1_, t2_] := 0.25 ((2 (Cos[t1] - Cos[t2]))/(-t1 + t2) - 2 Sin[t2])^4 + 
  0.25 (-Cos[t2] + (-Sin[t1] + Sin[t2])/(-t1 + t2))^4
```

[image]

Comment: See also [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/127161/find-where-a-parametric-equation-overlaps/127163#127163) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/126847/equation-solving-intersection-of-graphs/126852#126852).

Answer (score 1):

If you literally want the points that show up in the plot, try and rip them out of the `GraphicsComplex` that pops up in the `FullForm` of your plot. Here's an example:

```
Clear[q, r];
q[t1_, t2_] := 
 0.25*(2*(Cos[t1] - Cos[t2])/(t2 - t1) - 2*Sin[t1])^4 + 
  0.25 (-Cos[t1] + (Sin[t2] - Sin[t1])/(t2 - t1))^4;
r[t1_, t2_, En_] := 
 0.25` ((2 (Cos[t1] - Cos[t2]))/(-t1 + t2) - 2 Sin[t2])^4 + 
  0.25` (-Cos[t2] + (-Sin[t1] + Sin[t2])/(-t1 + t2))^4 - En;
Module[{plot = 
 Show[{ContourPlot[{q[t1, t2] == 1, 
   r[t1, t2, 0.4] == 0}, {t1, -\[Pi], 2*\[Pi]}, {t2, 0, 10 \[Pi]},
   ContourStyle -> {Lighter[Brown, .7], GrayLevel[.7]}], 
 ContourPlot[
  q[t1, t2] == 1, {t1, -\[Pi], 2*\[Pi]}, {t2, 0, 10 \[Pi]}, 
  ContourStyle -> None, 
  MeshFunctions -> Function[{t1, t2}, r[t1, t2, 0.4]], 
  Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[4.5]]]}],
points , index
},
points = plot[[1, 2, 1]];
index = Flatten@
  Cases[
    plot[[1, 2, 2]], 
    Point[{x___?NumberQ}] :> {x}, {0, \[Infinity]}];
    points[[index]]
]
```

I did some manual inspection to find out where the points you're interested in are hiding in the plot, but with some smart pattern matching you can probably generalise this example.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I added left out the function definitions before because I was in kind of a hurry, but I now added them for convenience. For me this code now definitely works in a fresh kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did, I think it does what you want but I am not sure I get the same number of points, a smaller step might get more (reduce .02 to something smaller for a much greater delay):

```
sols1 = DeleteDuplicates@{t1, t2} /.Table[
FindRoot[{q[t1, t2] == 1, 
     r[t1, t2, 0.4] == 0}, {{t1, z1}, {t2, z2}}],
   {z1, -\[Pi], 2*\[Pi], .02}, {z2, 0, 10 \[Pi], .02}];
```

After that long calculation, I show the points:

```
    Show@Graphics[
      Point@sols1,
      Axes -> True,
      PlotRange -> {{-\[Pi], 2 \[Pi]}, {0, 10 \[Pi]}},
      AspectRatio->1]
```

and I get:

[image]

Comment: This works, but the plot-based approach seems much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Simply save the graph as `plot` (`plot = Show[...`) and extract the points with:

```
pts = Cases[Normal@plot, Point[a_] :> a, Infinity]
ListPlot[pts]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can then refine the points using `FindRoot` and the initial conditions given by the plot, with

```
Table[{t1, t2} /. FindRoot[{q[t1, t2] - 1, r[t1, t2, 0.4]},
  {{t1, pts[[i, 1]]}, {t2, pts[[i, 2]]}}, AccuracyGoal -> Infinity], 
  {i, Length@pts}]
```